# Binding with Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So I have this problem, where the data is not being shown in a table.

My View Model:

```
var my = {};
my.viewModel = {
    Person: ko.observableArray([
        { name: "Alireza", family: "Davoodi", city: "Tehran", date: new Date().getTime() },
        { name: "Alireza", family: "Davoodi", city: "Tehran", date: new Date().getTime() },
        { name: "Alireza", family: "Davoodi", city: "Tehran", date: new Date().getTime() },
        { name: "Alireza", family: "Davoodi", city: "Tehran", date: new Date().getTime() },
        { name: "Alireza", family: "Davoodi", city: "Tehran", date: new Date().getTime() },
    ])
};

ko.applyBindings(my.viewModel);
```

View:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Person" >
    <tr>
        <td data-bibd="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bibd="text: family"></td>
        <td data-bibd="text: city"></td>
        <td data-bibd="text: date"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The data is not shown in the table; where am I going wrong?

The output I get is: `[object,object]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Person: ko.observableArray([
        { name: ko.observable("Alireza"), family: ko.observable("Davoodi"), city:ko.observable("Tehran"), date:ko.observable(new Date().getTime()) },   ])
```

All json values are placed on ko.observable.

Answer (score 12):

You have a typo: `data-bibd` should be `data-bind`. The rest [seems](http://jsfiddle.net/PajjL/) to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is the typo spinningarrow refers. Also there is a slight problem in your JSON formatting (the comma in the last line).

Also, I believe a better implementation (retaining the object oriented approach of knockout) would be this:

```
var my = {};
my.viewModel = function () {
    this.Person = ko.observableArray([{
        name: "Alireza",
        family: "Davoodi",
        city: "Tehran",
        date: new Date().getTime()
    }, {
        name: "Alireza",
        family: "Davoodi",
        city: "Tehran",
        date: new Date().getTime()
    }, {
        name: "Alireza",
        family: "Davoodi",
        city: "Tehran",
        date: new Date().getTime()
    }, {
        name: "Alireza",
        family: "Davoodi",
        city: "Tehran",
        date: new Date().getTime()
    }, {
        name: "Alireza",
        family: "Davoodi",
        city: "Tehran",
        date: new Date().getTime()
    } ]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new my.viewModel());
```

You can see it [working in JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/spitoglou/YxBqq/)

Comment: Don't throw tomatoes but what you are referring to as JSON is actually a javascript object literal.